# How can I list all useable implicit conversion?

Tags: scala

I know that in SCALA I can convert a type to another by define some implicit function, my question is , how can I know what conversions can I use after importing tons of packages?

For example, I have a string, and than how can I know what types can it convert to ?

Edit to clarify, I wanna do it in my scala compile plugin, so I may need to call a function on a reflect.api.tree  type, and then get the implicits. I am looking some method to use the implicitly[] mentioned in the answer.

Comment: It might be an idea to clarify this question - I think you want to know how to do this programatically, so that you can do it in a certain place in your code (as opposed to in the REPL).  That's certainly what _I_ want to know :)

Comment: @GreenAsJade yes, I edited my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the REPL you can invoke `:implicits` to see all the in-scope implicits other than those available from the Predef. (Add `-v` to see Predef implicits as well.)

You can also invoke the `implicitly[]` function from anywhere in your code to test for particular implicits.

```
scala> implicitly[String => Seq[Char]]
res0: String => Seq[Char] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[String => Array[Char]]
<console>:12: error: No implicit view available from String => Array[Char].
       implicitly[String => Array[Char]]
                 ^
```

Comment: Can I call implicitly for a value in my program?? Like implicitly["hello".getClass] ?

Comment: The `implicitly[]` function is very simple: `def implicitly[T](implicit e: T) = e` It simply pulls down the implicit that matches the type parameter (if it exists) and returns it.  It should work for any implicits in scope.

Comment: I tried to use it in REPL, it's useful to check if a conversion exist, but not showing all conversions that I can use. I think this can be a direction for me, but not the final answer for my question.But I should still say thanks to you,

Answer (score 3):

In **scala repl**, you can use `:implicits -v` to list all `implicits` under this context, like:

```
/* 69 implicit members imported from scala.Predef */
  /* 7 inherited from scala */
  final implicit class ArrayCharSequence extends CharSequence
  final implicit class ArrowAssoc[A] extends AnyVal
  final implicit class Ensuring[A] extends AnyVal
  final implicit class RichException extends AnyVal
  final implicit class SeqCharSequence extends CharSequence
  final implicit class StringFormat[A] extends AnyVal
  final implicit class any2stringadd[A] extends AnyVal
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I accepted jwvh's answer but his answer can only work for normal user. I fond a tricky way to do it in a compiler plugin, the code is not for common usage so I don't paste it here, if any of you are interesting about how to get all implicit values in compiler plugin, you can refer to my github[Scala-completion-Base](https://github.com/johnzeng/Scala-completion-Base/blob/master/plug.scala)